# Is it possible to include calls in Declarative Pipelines in the shared library (Jenkins)?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

As you know in [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) in Jenkins, it is possible to call in the Jenkinsfile a content of a file in vars folder.

For example in vars folder in the shared library we can have a file named `build.groovy` and in the Jenkinsfile we can call it by :

`build {
  parameter1 = "some param1"
  parameter2 = "some param2"
}`

As it is described in [this section](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps) .
I have no problems having groovy files and calling them with `call()` method in Jenkinsfile.

But I want to customize a pipeline and make it as generic as possible.
So I want to call a groovy file contained in `vars` folder but in the same pipeline : Calling a `genericStage.groovy` in an other file contained in the same vars folder in the shared library.

So what I have is a groovy file in `vars` folder : `genericStage.groovy`
What I have is :

```
Pipeline{
 agent{label myNode}

 stages{

  stage("init"){
   //steps

  }

  genericStage{
   parameter1 = "some param"
  }

 }

}
```

And in the genericStage :

```
def call(Closure body) {
def config = [:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
body()

stage(config.parameter1){
    steps{
        //steps
    }
}
```

}

But I get the error :

```
Expected a stage @ line 125, column 6.
                genericStage{
    ^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
```

So how to make calls in the same shared library as we do for the Jenkinsfile ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370215/how-to-share-a-declarative-pipeline-across-many-projects) might solve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

In your shared library method defining a DSL style step like this you can either define a block of steps and script that does some common processing you need to share between jobs or stages in a job or a whole complete pipeline. So your genericStage.groovy can only contain what comes after the "// steps" comment and cannot contain the stage and steps definition like this. I do this type of library custom step quite a lot in the style you have here but without trying to define the stage / steps inside it and it works fine. What is happening for you here is the pipeline validation  / parser is failing the main pipeline syntax before it even gets to handling your custom step because you don't have it wrapped in a stage and steps definition.

If you read the documentation link you have at the end there is a section on defining a complete declarative pipeline in a shared library. It says at the end "Only entire pipeline`s can be defined in shared libraries as of this time. This can only be done in`vars/*.groovy, and only in a call method. Only one Declarative Pipeline can be executed in a single build, and if you attempt to execute a second one, your build will fail as a result." This suggests that a partial pipeline like you have won't work, you should have just steps / script or a complete pipeline.